# Trying to GET rabbit msg without ack, but no success

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

I have a task in which I try to get all the messages in a rabbit queue. I only need to GET, and not CONSUME.
So here is the code, I am using

```
def some_function_name() :
    connection = rabbitObj.get_connection()
    channel = rabbitObj.get_channel(connection)
    while True : 
        method_frame, header_frame, body = channel.basic_get(queue='error_queue', no_ack=False)
        if method_frame:
            #do some work
        else :
             break #breaking the loop

while(True):
    some_function_name()
```

when I run this code, it works properly,first time.I get all the messages in queue and and all messages remain in 'Ready' state, but when I run the loop second time, all messages turn change to 'Unacknowledged' state.

Requirement : Every time I should only GET messages,and they should not go Unacknowledged.

First Loop:

[image: First Loop]

Second Loop :

[image]

Can anyone help me with, what I am doing wrong, or what changes should I make.

Thanks in advance :)

Edit 1:
As for @BarrensZeppelin 's answer, all msgs are lost, if I set no_ack=True. Check the below screenshot : 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a workaround, and it is working.
Closing the rabbit connection, after consuming did the trick.(though now it is taking time to create and close a connection everytime)

```
def some_function_name() :
    connection = rabbitObj.get_connection()
    channel = rabbitObj.get_channel(connection)
    while True : 
        method_frame, header_frame, body = channel.basic_get(queue='error_queue', no_ack=False)
        if method_frame:
            #do some work
        else :
             break #breaking the loop
    rabbitObj.close_connection(connection)

while(True):
    some_function_name()
```

Comment: You could use basic_cancel instead, this should allow you to use the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `no_ack=False` you specifically tell the broker to expect a reply, which is why all the messages become Unacknowledged. Try setting `no_ack=True`.

Comment: In that case, all the messages get lost. Adding a screenshot in question for this case.

Comment: Aha, so you want to browse the queue. This is not supported in RabbitMQ, but there are work-arounds.
Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700292/using-rabbitmq-is-there-a-way-to-look-at-the-queue-contents-without-a-dequeue

Comment: There is no GET action in RabbitMQ as you think of it. What you are really doing is consuming all the messages.

Put simply: basic_consume is for consuming multiple messages in a row efficiently and blocks until messages become available, basic_get always returns a single message (if available - otherwise None).